# Filtering array of objects based on array

Tags: typescript

I am trying to filter one array of objects that looks like this

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' }
];
```

And an array that looks like this

```
const values = [1,5];
```

What I need is to filter `ELEMENT_DATA` to `NEW_VALUES` look like this

```
const NEW_VALUES: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' }
];
```

I have tried with filter like this:

```
  filterData(locationName: any) {
    return ELEMENT_DATA.filter(object => {
      return object.position === locationName;
    });
  }
```

but always I get an empty array.

Comment: Is locationName your array of numbers? If so 1. why type it as any? And 2. Did you think e.g. `1 === [1, 5]`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `locationName` gets as input `[1,5]` then the code should look like this:

```
 filterData(locationName: number[]) {
    return ELEMENT_DATA.filter(object => {
      return locationName.includes(object.position);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
ELEMENT_DATA.filter(function (object) {
  return locationName.indexOf(object.position) !== -1; // -1 means not present
});
```

or with underscore JS , using the same predicate:

```
_.filter(ELEMENT_DATA, function (object) {
  return locationName.indexOf(object.position) !== -1; // -1 means not present
}
```

If you have access to ES6 collections or a polyfill for [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).
Here **locationName** should be a type of Set

```
ELEMENT_DATA.filter(object=> locationName.has(object.position))
```